# VBS - Ignoring the \ special character properties

Tags: string, vbscript, escaping, quotation-marks

I'm struggling to call a command line correctly in VBS due to the \ escape character.

The string output I'm looking to write to the command line is,

```
batch_name=\"myBatch\"
```

Which gets passed to a .exe file. Unfortunately, due to the way the \ character works I can only write,

```
batch_name=\myBatch\
batch_name=\""myBatch\""
```

I can't get \" in the output! An altered version of my code is below,

```
BATCH_NAME = "myBatch"

outputString = "batch_name=\" & BATCH_NAME & "\"
```

I've tried lots of methods - Concatenating the string with Chr(34), using multiple double quotes, even trying to replace() "" with ", nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a shot and

```
outputString = "batch_name=\""" & BATCH_NAME & "\"""
```

worked for me giving the result `batch_name=\"myBatch\"`

Does it work for you? How you execute this command in the shell?

Comment: You are right, this works in a simple test environment, but it outputs \""myBatch\"" when run in the whole code. There must be something else in my code which is causing the error.

Perhaps it's because BATCH_NAME is being passed as an argument from another .vbs file, and the string passed over has spaces?

I don't have the file in front of me, but this line is part of a string of parameters passed over to another system, called through wscript.run()

Comment: Without more data (the passed argoument for example) or more code I'm afraid I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following;

```
outputString = "batch_name=" & chr(92) & chr(34) & BATCH_NAME & chr(92) & chr(34)
```